# loop with accumulator on an rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to loop n times where n is an accumulator over the same rdd

lets say n = 10 so I want the code bellow to loop 5 times (since the accumulator is increased by two)

```
val key = keyAcm.value.toInt
val rest = rdd.filter(_._1 > (key + 1))
val combined = rdd.filter(k => (k._1 == key) || (k._1 == key + 1))
                  .map(x => (key, x._2))
                  .reduceByKey { case (x, y) => (x ++ y) }
keyAcm.add(2)
combined.union(rest)
```

with this code I filter the rdd and keep keys 0 (init value of accumulator) and 1. Then, I am trying to merge its second parameter and change the key to create a new rdd with key 0 and a merged array. After that, I union this rdd with the original one leaving behind the filtered values (0 and 1). Lastly, I increase the accumulator by two.How can I repeat theses steps until the accumulator is 10?

any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you please remove all specific details from you question and keep only essential. Accumulators are not supposed to be used like that. Writing to accumulator must happen only on workers (inside `map`, `filter`, etc.), not on the driver. And reading from accumulator must happen only on the driver. You are doing vise-versa.

Comment: I want to merge the second parameter for every two keys without causing a suffle

Answer (score -1):

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = ???
val res: RDD[(Int, Iterable[String])] = rdd.map(x => (x._1 / 2, x._2)).groupByKey()
```

Comment: val rdd: RDD[(Int,Array[Int])]  will your answer trigger a suffle?

Comment: If the data for k=1 and k=2 reside on different partitions there is no way to combine it w/o a shuffle.